# Prevent background image from stretching the view

Tags: android

Whenever I assign background to a view that is laid out with wrap_content, if the background image is larger than a view, the view is stretched so that it can hold the entire background. Why is it so and how to prevent it? It occurs even if the image is 9-patch and has stretchable areas marked - why isn't the image shrunk to the size of the view?

Comment: Hmm, not sure but did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8501398/568508

Comment: This does not work for shrinking the background

Answer (score 11):

You can use RelativeLayout and create two elements inside it. An ImageView for the Background and another view for your content. Use the `android:layout_alignBottom` to the the ImageView and set the value to the id of your content view. Also set the scaleType of the ImageView to fitXY.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_gravity="center" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="@drawable/chronometer_bg"
  android:id="@+id/imageView_chronometerBackground"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chronometer" />

<Chronometer android:text="Chronometer"
      android:id="@+id/chronometer" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="32sp"
      android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Either override the methods [getSuggestedMinimumWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getSuggestedMinimumWidth()) and [getSuggestedMinimumHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getSuggestedMinimumHeight()) of your layout view or the methods [getMinimumWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getMinimumWidth()) and [getMinimumHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getMinimumHeight()) of your background drawable to achieve that.

Comment: Code-based solutions are really heavy for something that should be so simple

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the width and height to something like `60dp` instead of `wrap_content` and use `android:scaleType`.

Comment: Sometimes I just don't know how big view will be (e.g. a balloon with a TextView inside it).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a background, you can use a FrameLayout with an ImageView as the first element.  Then use android:scaleType="center" so the image won't scale.  It will always be it's original size, and centered.  Then you can put whatever views you like on top of it in the FrameLayout.

Comment: I don't want it to be the original size, I want it to shrink to the size of a view.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a crazy idea, but how about creating a special nine-patch image like this:

- take the original image
- add 2 pixel border around it (1 pixel border for the 9-patch marking, and 1 pixel empty border)
- mark the empty border as stretchable

This way you will have 2 stretchable areas horizontally, and 2 vertically, which is the empty border. Thus the center of the image (your original image remains unscaled)

Btw, this might not be the best solution, but since the others already listed the nice solutions, I thought I add this one as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it so? Because you set the width to `wrap_content`.

How can you prevent it:

a. Set the `maxWidth` attribute.

b. Try placing the `ImageView` with `wrap_content` inside a Layout that has a fixed width.

c. (I often use TableLayout as its shrinkColumns and stretchColumns attribute are handy for things like this. Maybe this can work for you too.)

Too help more, some XML is needed.

Comment: A background isn't content. Suggesting wrap_content should be affected by the background size is logically inconsistent with the asker's question. [Edit: I'm not saying droid doesn't work that way--clearly it does--but the original question was *why* it works that way and what to do about it, not *whether* it works that way.]