# How to implement an android:background that doesn't stretch?

Tags: android, android-layout

I found this [great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318629/imagebutton-in-android) describing how to "eat the cake and have it too", i.e. use image for a `Button` instead of `ImageButton` (which doesn't allow `SetText()`, resizing, etc.).

This is achieved by using the View attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/bgimage"
```

The only problem with this is that it stretches the image to fit the button size.

Short of hard-coding a fixed button size (in pixels!), is there a way to tell Android **not** to stretch the background image at all and either crop or pad it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) if you don't want it to stretch.
Background images will always stretch to fit the view.
You need to set it as a Drawable to force the image aspect to the object.

Otherwise, if you are sticking with the Button idea, then you will need to force the scaling in the button to prevent the image from stretching.

Code:

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  // Set content layout, etc up here

  // Now adjust button sizes
  Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.somebutton);
  int someDimension = 50; //50pixels
  b.setWidth(someDimension);
  b.setHeight(someDimension);
}
```

Comment: Thanks + 1. `ImageView` looks interesting. I noticed it has an attribute that's not in `Button`: `android:cropToPadding`. I don't mind using an ImageView instead, as long as it has `setOnClickListener()` -- which it does. What will I be losing by switching from `Button` to `ImageView`?

Comment: BTW, the 2nd solution you suggested still stretches the image.

Comment: I ended up using fixed button size (in pixels!) but I am accepting your answer because the 1st suggestion looks like a working alternative solution.

Comment: @ef2011 For ImageView, don't set it as a background image, you have to set it as a `setDrawableResource` and then make sure `setAdjustViewBounds` is set to true

Comment: Downvoted for a lame solution. Correct solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9362168/145046

Answer (score 268):

You can create an xml bitmap and use it as background for the view. To prevent stretching you can specify `android:gravity` attribute.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dvdr"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

There are a lot of options you can use to customize the rendering of the image

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap

Comment: Using ImageViews is a workaround which isn't always a possible option - I believe this to be the proper solution :)

Comment: I am setting background at run time. Is any solution to create bitmap at run time?

Comment: for me this was the best solution but removing the "gravity" attribute, which makes it match its default value "fill". This will allow image resize to fit the screen. Study @Santosh link for more info. Thanks!

Comment: I only see one problem with this approach. If the drawable source is already larger than the container, this will clip the image (based on gravity) rather than resizing it, maintaining the aspect ratio, to fit the container.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. Much better than the RelativeLayout approach. set gravity to bottom|left let me put the pencil icon behind the value. Used a little  right padding on the text. Kind liked having it behind but messed up when text got long.

Comment: I'd give you 50 upvotes if I could. Tried for ages but was too dumb to see this one.

Comment: Fantastic solution. Using this was the only way I could get my ScrollView to work properly. Thanks!

Comment: Does the `android:src` attribution can be changed by code to avoid make multiple xml files?

Comment: How can I do this if it's not a resource? What if I want to do this programatically with an image taken by the Camera?

Comment: Appears a bit dated now. This only works for bitmaps, and doesn't work for Vector drawables.

Comment: Problem is It won't cover the whole screen if the drawable height is shorter than the device's i.e., a tablet

Answer (score 27):

Simply using `ImageButton` instead of `Button` fixes the problem.

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="30dp"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:src="@drawable/bgimage" />
```

and you can set

```
android:background="@null"
```

to remove button background if you want.

Quick Fix !! :-)

Comment: And then set the image with the setImageResource() method ... that worked for me.

Comment: i wanted both image and background colour in a button ... this worked like a charm

Comment: It works more accurately for me (I mean - "layout_centerVertical", for example).

Answer (score 13):

I am using an ImageView in an RelativeLayout that overlays with my normal layout. No code required.
It sizes the image to the full height of the screen (or any other layout you use) and then crops the picture left and right to fit the width. In my case, if the user turns the screen, the picture may be a tiny bit too small. Therefore I use match_parent, which will make the image stretch in width if too small.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        //comment: Stretches picture in the width if too small. Use "wrap_content" does not stretch, but leaves space

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        //in my case I always want the height filled

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        //will crop picture left and right, so it fits in height and keeps aspect ratio

        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This actually a much easier solution for a problem that shouldn't exist

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem: you should only use a 9-patch image (.9.png) instead of your original picture.

Serge

Answer (score 5):

Use **draw9patch**... included within Android Studio's SDK tools.  You can define the stretchable areas of your image.  Important parts are constrained and the image doesn't look all warped.  A good demo on dra9patch is [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMkuqZC3CxE)

Use draw9patch to change your existing splash.png into new_splash.9.png,
drag new_splash.9.png into the drawable-hdpi project folder
ensure the AndroidManifest and styles.xml are proper as below:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
...
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenStyle"
>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="splashScreenStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/new_splash</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a background image, not big in size, but with weird dimensions - therefore the stretching and bad performance. I made a method with parameters Context, a View and a drawable ID(int) that will match the device screen size. Use this in e.g a Fragments onCreateView to set the background.

```
public void setBackground(Context context, View view, int drawableId){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),drawableId);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Resources.getSystem().
             getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
             Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels,
             true);

    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), 
                                    bitmap);

    view.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of Santosh's answer for programmatically-created buttons, without the need for a separate XML configuration:

```
Button button = new Button(getContext());
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_button);
BitmapDrawable backgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), backgroundBitmap);
backgroundDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // also LEFT, CENTER_VERTICAL, etc.
backgroundDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
button.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
```

I included the ColorFilter line since that works a little differently from buttons with a normal background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FrameLayout` with an `ImageView` as the first child, then your normal layout as the second child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"/>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_actual_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set the drawable as the image of the button, not as a background. Like this:

```
rb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.whatever_drawable);
```

Comment: This is a method of CompoundButton but not of Button.

Answer (score 0):

One can use a plain ImageView in his xml and make it clickable 
 (android:clickable="true")?
You only have to use as src an image that has been shaped like a button i.e round corners.