# How do I keep my splash screen's background from stretching?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How do I go about setting the background for a splash screen that does not stretch, and maintains a density-independent size? Here's a visual of what I'm trying to go for:

[image]

I have a large image file (1000x1000px) of the background. I want the background to maintain its density-independent size, with the excess just not visible, so that it will be displayed correctly on various screen sizes. I also want the center of the image anchored to the center of the screen. (the image above is just a mockup, the focal point should be at the center of the image)

How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902230/how-to-implement-an-androidbackground-that-doesnt-stretch - Does this help?

Comment: Hmm, but won't the ImageView have a maximum size of that of its Layout container? Can I get the ImageView to extend out past the Layout?

Comment: I belive that if you set your ImageView layout_width as wrap_content and height has wrap_content it will extend. However, as an alternative solution you can set the width and the height as 1000x1000px :)

Comment: Posted the answer for future reference of anyone who tries to and find this. Hope that you used this anwser. Otherwise, let me know :).

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida, this is what I'm getting: http://goo.gl/L8hmH

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27544/discussion-between-tiago-almeida-and-michael-zimmerman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [link here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902230/how-to-implement-an-androidbackground-that-doesnt-stretch) that might help.

You can use an `ImageView` as your background (otherwise backgrounds of any view will just stretch).

And use it as the background of your ImageView. Your `ImageView` can then have the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` as `wrap_content`.

Then, set the [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) as `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Note that this ImageView has to be the first element of your layout. Otherwise it will just hide everything in your layout.

Comment: It's still not working for me. I even tried programmatically setting setMinimumHeight() and setMinimumWidth() on the ImageView object. Nothing. Looks just like this layout editor: goo.gl/L8hmH

Comment: Try to join the discussion I opened above and I can help you more properly. I don't have the androidSDK installed in this machine so this is the only way to help you out :/