# Android: multiple screen size drawable folders needed when using xml bitmap?

Tags: android, xml, image, bitmap

This is a follow up question to: [How to implement an android:background that doesn't stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902230/how-to-implement-an-androidbackground-that-doesnt-stretch).

Santosh's solution works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dvdr"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

but I have a question to the note of the developers page:

> Note: Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image
>   compression by the aapt tool during the build process. For example, a
>   true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors may be
>   converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. This will result in an
>   image of equal quality but which requires less memory. So be aware
>   that the image binaries placed in this directory can change during the
>   build. If you plan on reading an image as a bit stream in order to
>   convert it to a bitmap, put your images in the res/raw/ folder
>   instead, where they will not be optimized.

When I place the bitmap xml file inside the drawable folder and a default `dvdr` file of the biggest size and best quality in there as well, does that mean that I can always omit the multiple screen size folders like `drawable-xxxhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`,..., that would mean that I don't need to create screen size optimized images for each folder anymore, is that right? If this works so, why do I need the multiple drawable files at all, since I could let do the job by Android.