# How to set background for all activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set background for all activities in adnroid application and keep it's aspect ratio?

I am using `android:windowBackground` in style, but I don't know, how to keep aspect ratio for my background image.

Is there only way to add `ImageView` with background for all activities manually?

Comment: Make your own `BaseActivity` class, have all other Activity classes extend from that?

Comment: It sounds like an a good idea. And how can I set background for this?

Comment: Something like so, however, I see this not being an ideal solution for drawing additional content on top of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135984/full-screen-background-image-in-an-activity

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to set the background in the `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullBackground" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">#757575</item>
</style>
```

(Where `AppTheme` might be a theme you already defined, and I just used a grey color there, but it can be a drawable)

Then add to your Manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name=".FooActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullBackground">
</activity>
```

Since you have to add activities to the Manifest anyway, this is a good way to check if all the activities have the background. You, of course, could still extend the `BaseActivity` and only have the `BaseActivity` class maintain the theme setting.

Comment: Well, I've **already** use `android:background` to set background image, but it's strethced and ugly

Comment: Your question has windowBackground, not background, but I see what you're saying, and I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902230/how-to-implement-an-androidbackground-that-doesnt-stretch

Comment: "background" attribute used for all views
you must use "windowBackground" instead of background if you want work for activities only.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own base activity as an abstract class and make every other activity in your application extend from that:

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // this is a generic way of getting your root view element
        View rootView = (View) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image));        
    }
}
```

Then you should extend that in your desired activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity
```