# Android layout height issue

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I have a RelativeLayout and I have some TextViews & ImageViews inside it. I have an image set as a background for the RelativeLayout whose height is more than the total height of the child views. So, it's leaving some blank space apart form child views at the bottom. So, how can I avoid this blank space? I mean, is it possible to make the layout height exactly equal to the total height of the child views without considering the height of the layout's background image?
**Ex:**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg_image">
    <TextView />
    <ImageView /> 
</RelativeLayout/>
```

Here, height of 'bg_image' is more than total height of TextView & ImageView. So, it leaves some blank space after TextView & ImageView

Comment: Add the xml content what have you done ..and what you need to do!!

Comment: Edited in the question...

Comment: Please somebody edit my sample code to standard format...

Comment: Hey Manjunath! Remove the code from the comment, Edit the question and put your code in it. 

The right way to add code to your question.

Comment: Did you guys get my question ?

Comment: if possible send some screen shorts or sample screens what you really want .

Comment: is 9-patch an option?
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163308/how-to-wrap-content-views-rather-than-background-drawable

Comment: Thanks Ameer for the awesome edit...

Comment: But, the background image has gradient. If 9-patch image is used, does it affect the gradient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `RelativeLayout` calculates it's height from it's background image. Try setting a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image instead. It will then stretch as much as needed to fill the layout, which should have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Yes, seems like 9-patch is the solution... But, I am worried about the gradient. Background image has a varying gradient.

Comment: It's possible to make a 9-patch with a gradient. Search for it. I don't keep those resources and can't just look and tell you how it's done :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `fill_parent` option.. i dont know how many controls are there in your **XML Layout**.. But may be `fill_parent` will help you..

Comment: Yes now from picture its clear.. You can set image as fill parent and assign weight to textview and imageview.. For example, `<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_image" android:weightsum="3">`

Comment: But, the child views (TextView & ImageView) should take their normal heights. instead, RelativeLayout should shrink according to child views height.

Comment: give total weight as weightsum in relative layout and then layout weight to textview and imageview..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_image">
    <TextView />
    <ImageView /> 
</RelativeLayout/>
```